# Prove $A$ positive definite $\Rightarrow$ $A$ invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

At the demonstration of this, I couldn't understand why the following holds:

"$A$ positive definite $\Rightarrow$ $A$ invertible, because otherwise would exist $X\not=0$ satisfying $AX=0\Rightarrow X^TAX=0$ wich is a contradiction."

I understood the implications, but couldn't get why "$A$ not invertible then exist $X\not=0$ satisfying $AX=0$"

If anyone could explain this to me or give another way of proving the initial problem, I'd be gratefull.

Comment: If $Ax=0$ implies $x=0$, then $A$ is invertible.

Comment: A matrix is singular (i.e. non-invertible) iff its determinant (i.e. the product of the eigenvalues) equals zero. A positive-definite matrix has a positive determinant, hence it cannot be singular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n$ be the number of columns, if $A$ is not invertible, its rank is less than $n$ and its nullity is at least $1$.

Hence there exists $x \neq 0$, such that $Ax=0$.